# Не могу вывести данные через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Получила данные с помощью ajax, записала в массив чтобы вывести в таблицу с помощью DataTable. В консоле виден массив, но таблица не заполняется. Не могу понять в чем ошибка

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>

<script>
    let obj = [];
    let info = [];
    let infoForTables = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/',
        success: response => {
            for (let i in response) {
                obj.push(`${response[i].alpha2Code} ${response[i].flag} ${response[i].name}                        ${response[i].capital} ${response[i].population}`);
                for (let j in obj) {
                    info = obj[j].split(' ', 6);
                }
                infoForTables.push(info);
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(infoForTables);

    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: infoForTables,
        columns: [
            { title: "Code" },
            { title: "Flag" },
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Capital" },
            { title: "Population" }
        ]
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/botagoz/u0s7opfx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаете таблицу раньше чем приходят данные

```
    let obj = [];
    let info = [];
    let infoForTables = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/',
        success: response => {
            for (let i in response) {
                obj.push(`${response[i].alpha2Code} ${response[i].flag} ${response[i].name} ${response[i].capital} ${response[i].population}`);
                for (let j in obj) {
                    info = obj[j].split(' ', 6);
                }
                infoForTables.push(info);
            }
            
            $('#example').DataTable({
              data: infoForTables,
                columns: [
                { title: "Code" },
                { title: "Flag" },
                { title: "Name" },
                { title: "Capital" },
                { title: "Population" }
            ]
          });
        }
    });

    console.log(infoForTables);
```

так работает

либо так

```
    let obj = [];
    let info = [];
    let infoForTables = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/',
        success: response => {
            for (let i in response) {
                obj.push(`${response[i].alpha2Code} ${response[i].flag} ${response[i].name}                        ${response[i].capital} ${response[i].population}`);
                for (let j in obj) {
                    info = obj[j].split(' ', 6);
                }
                infoForTables.push(info);
            }

          table.clear();
          table.rows.add(infoForTables).draw();
        }
    });

    console.log(infoForTables);

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data: infoForTables,
        columns: [
            { title: "Code" },
            { title: "Flag" },
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Capital" },
            { title: "Population" }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Галочка рядом принять ответ